# R: Apply an integrative function to a dataset

Tags: r

here is my question:

I want to calculate an integrated index of chlorophyl a concentration through a depth profile over time.
Every day, a water column sample was taken in order to determine chlorophyll a concentration. My dataset is organized this way:

Col 1 = Day of the month, Col 2 = Depth at which the sample was collected and Col 5 = Chlorophyll a concentration at that depth.

```
    day depth  chla
 1,1.1,NA

 1,2.6,NA

 1,5.0,NA

 1,9.9,NA

 1,15.0,NA

 1,24.8,NA

 1,49.5,NA

 1,1.1,NA

 1,2.6,0.49

 1,5.0,0.46

 1,10.0,0.75

 1,15.1,0.41

 1,25.0,0.29

 1,49.9,0.26

 2,1.0,0.17

 2,10.0,0.24

 3,0.8,NA

 3,2.5,NA

 3,5.0,NA

[...]
```

The integrated way to calculate chlorophyll a concentration goes as follow:

For each day and for depths from 0 to 50 meters,

The chlorophyll a concentration at each pair of depths is averaged, then multiplied by the difference between the two depths to get a total concentration in that depth interval. These depth interval values are then summed over the entire depth range to get the integrated production rate of that particular day.

So, I want to get the integrated concentration of chlorophyll a for each day in order to assess temporal variations in the primary production.

If anyone could help me writing the script, that would be really appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: What have you tried ( http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ ) ?

Comment: You should post your data (or part of it) in a reproducible format- perhaps by using `dput` on the R object

Comment: I suspect you'll find it easier going if you look at `sort` and related functions to get all measurements for a given day in depth order.  At that point, it'll be pretty easy to sum over (calling the matrix "mydata") `(mydata[i,2]-mydata[i-1,2]) * mydata[i,3]` , or something close to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ddply](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/plyr/html/ddply-5k.html) from the [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) package to split the table by day, apply the function, and recombine. For each day, the integrate function below multiplies the pairs of averages by the difference in depth. (I invent some fake data as an example)

```
concentrations = data.frame(day=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                            depth=c(1.1, 2.6, 11, 4, 6, 15),
                            chla=c(1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 9))


library(plyr)

integrate = function(x) {
    averages = (x$chla[1:length(x)-1] + x$chla[2:length(x)]) / 2
    sum(averages * diff(x$depth))
}

result = ddply(concentrations, .(day), integrate)
print(result)
```

Comment: 'Fess up, @David: did you peek at my comment first?  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: honestly I didn't! I was absorbed in the code.